# difference between c-statistics and AUC for prediction performance

Tags: r, predictive-models, auc

I have two types of outcome from a big dataset and I performed prediction models and checked the prediction performance using 10-fold cross-validation, so:

1. for binary outcome: lasso logistic regression, then I calculated AUC after 10-fold cross-validation
2. for time-to-event outcome: lasso cox model, then I calculated AUC, using R package "`Hmisc`" and function `rcorr.cens`. here is the code line just to show: `AUC = 1-rcorr.cens(x, Surv(time,status))['C Index']`

now my question is that:

1. for each model, which of AUC or c-statistics is appropriate? should I report AUC or c-statistics or both? why?
2. this code gives me the AUC, is it correct? `1-rcorr.cens(x, Surv(time,status))['C Index'] and changing to` rcorr.cens(x, Surv(time,status))['C Index']` gives me the c-statistcis, is it true?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That's mainly true.  In Cox regression we usually take one minus $c$ because the linear predictor is such that high values $\Rightarrow$ shorter survival time.  Note that $c$ is a generalization of AUROC and is computed **during** cross-validation or bootstrap using for example the R `rms` package `validate` function.  It is important to correct for overfitting, which `validate` does.  The default is bootstrapping but you can use C-V instead.  Note that for comparing models $c$ and AUROC are not adequate..  See [this](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue).

Comment: thank you for your response. 10-fold cross-validation has been done. thank you for the link. It is great what you have shared in the link. However, there are many published papers reporting AUC or c-statistics. I would like to know which one should be used for which type of outcome. Is it necessary to report c-statistics in addition to AUC?

Comment: @EdM if you can provide your answer would be great

Comment: Since $c$ is a generalization of AUROC the follow-up question doesn't make complete sense to me.  Note that a single 10-fold CV is insufficient; you may need 100 repeats of that, averaging the results.  $c$ statistics are useful summaries that are especially interpretable but since they are not log-likelihood based they should be de-emphasized.  See [this](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue) and [this](https://hbiostat.org/bib/r2.html), the latter link showing that it's easy to get adjusted $R^2$ whereas for $c$ and AUROC we don't have indexes that adjust for overfitting.